# Regarding CSV import in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have a csv file like 3*3 like 3 row and 3 column like this

```
value1 value2 value3
value1 value2 value3
value1 value2 value3
```

and a table with 3 coulmns like

```
column1 column2 column3
```

how can I programmatically import the CSV data in database and want to show in other page also.. So how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If from table you mean you have content type, you can use feeds module to import csv and map with the content type fields.

Comment: no i dont have any content type.. just i want to create a form with CSV import and want to save in DB(if possible) or i want to show the csv file in form of table

Comment: If i understand you correct, you will have to do this using the drupal way. either create custom module to do all this or use feeds module, content type and views to accomplish this.

Comment: Without using Content types and views and no external module will use just we will create one custom module and use that functionalit, if we can then please tell me how?

Comment: Yes, your custom module will create a custom drupal form, then in your form submit function you can process the csv and store value into your db table created by your custom module's  .install file. For displaying csv data you can use hook_menu to create path and page. Follow this link to know how you can create a custom module https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/getting-started